# Open an .ods file in Libre Office via python

Tags: python, file, subprocess

Please go easy on me, I just started in Python.

I want to make a program which saves the time I spend in a file (for work). I can open Libre Office Calc via:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\scalc.exe'])
```

but this opens a new file. If I open the file I want to work in, Libre Office generates a new window with a new handle from which I do not know the ID (so I can not measure the runtime of this handle).

Is there any possibility to open the file directly? Or make an input where I can put in the link to open it?

Comment: I might be drifting a bit but is opening directly your file when launching libre office acceptable ? If so, you should be able to pass the file as a parameter.

Comment: @peyo It is acceptable. I tried to directly call it with `subprocess.call(['C:\Users\M3nsch\Desktop\\a.ods]'])` but this just gets me: `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`
How do I call it as a parameter?

Comment: When using subprocess, you should pass each parameter as a list with the binary you're trying to call, such as: `subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\scalc.exe', 'C:\\Users\\M3nsch\\Desktop\\a.ods'])`. In my case, `subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE', 'C:\\Users\\peyo\\Documents\\tests.xlsx'])` works fine :) Don't forget the double backslashes `\\` in both paths.

Comment: Your unicode error is caused by `\U` in `C:\Users...` which python interprets as a unicode character (which isn't the case). So when using `\\` it tells to use the special character `\` instead of the special character `\Users`. In my example, `\test` would be interpreted as `<TAB>est`, so .. no good for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @peyo Thank u for your help, I found a workarround!

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a workarround:
Instead of using Python to open the program I let pywinauto list me all programs and then write the name of the program down:

```
while True:
    x=1
    while x <= 2:
        windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
        print("If you do not find your program in the list write '@'")
        print("")
        for w in windows:
            if w.window_text()!="":
                print(str(w.window_text()))
        program_Open=str(input())
        if program_Open!="@":
            x=3
```

The `if w.window_text()!="":` is to delete emtpy lines in the list caused by backgroundprograms.